# Is it best practice to exclude the pagination query parameter in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, best-practices, query-string

Our site has 4 query parameters on site. They are all for the Blog section and only the pagination parameter can be added to another query parameter:

- Category
- Tag
- Author
- Pagination parameter

Obviously, category, tag, and author are all useful and essential since they are appearing alone. The pagination parameter is optional and is the only one that can start to mess up the other data. However, excluding the pagination parameter means that we will be unable to determine if users are going passed the first page of results.

**What is considered best practice for pagination parameters in Google Analytics?**

Answer (score 1):

We place this in our webshops `<head />`

```
<link rel="next" href="some-url/?page=3" />
<link rel="prev" href="some-url/?page=1" />
```

This indicated there are multiple pages of this result. We only want the first page ranked, and the others to be crawled and that exactly what's happening.
Because of this, GA never requires us to specify that part of the url.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn. I'm only interested in Google Analytics configuration though. Apologies if that wasn't clear.